# [rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/camilla/ros_workspace

Tags: ros-package-path, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rospack] opendir error [No such file or directory] while crawling /home/camilla/ros_workspace

What kind of error is this?
Because it appears on the shell but then my node is executed correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42027/%5Brospack%5D-opendir-error-%5Bno-such-file-or-directory%5D-while-crawling-/home/camilla/ros_workspace/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It probably means `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is not set correctly in your shell. Or, maybe your `ros_workspace` directory does not exist.

What do these commands return?

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
$ ls ~/ros_workspace
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0